# How can I adjust contrast in OpenCV in C?

Tags: c, opencv, image-processing, contrast

I'm just trying to adjust contrast/ brightness in an image in gray scale to highlight whites in that image with Opencv in C. How can I do that? is there any function that makes this task in opencv?

Original image:

[image]

Modified image:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is possible to adjust them in opencv. But it would be more useful if you could add an image, then explain what you want.

Comment: @Abid Rahman K Images added..

Comment: Is the second image you wanted as result? If so, how did you do it? the same can be done in Opencv

Comment: @Abid Rahman K I've done with photoshop :) . I've only corrected the contrast, but I want to do that with opencv

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you can adjust contrast here in two ways:

1) **[Histogram Equalization :](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_equalization)**

But when i tried this with your image, result was not as you expected. Check it below:

[image]

2) **Thresholding** :

Here, i compared each pixel value of input with an arbitrary value ( which i took `127`). Below is the logic which has inbuilt function in opencv. `But remember, output is Binary image, not grayscale as you did.`

```
If (input pixel value >= 127):
    ouput pixel value = 255
else:
    output pixel value = 0
```

And below is the result i got :

[image]

For this, you can use **[Threshold function](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?highlight=cv2.threshold#threshold)** or **[compare function](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=cv2.add#compare)**

3) **If you are compulsory to get grayscale image as output, do as follows**:

(code is in OpenCV-Python, but for every-function, corresponding C functions are available in opencv.itseez.com)

```
for each pixel in image:
   if pixel value >= 127: add 'x' to pixel value.
   else : subtract 'x' from pixel value.
```

( 'x' is an arbitrary value.) Thus difference between light and dark pixels increases.

```
img = cv2.imread('brain.jpg',0)

bigmask = cv2.compare(img,np.uint8([127]),cv2.CMP_GE)
smallmask = cv2.bitwise_not(bigmask)

x = np.uint8([90])
big = cv2.add(img,x,mask = bigmask)
small = cv2.subtract(img,x,mask = smallmask)
res = cv2.add(big,small)
```

And below is the result obtained:

[image]

Comment: Non of these address the question i.e. how to adjust contrast

Comment: it is true that question title is 'how to adjust contrast'. But what he wants to do in question is to highlight the white part in image. So i answered for that with whatever knowledge i have. And ofcourse, in comment, OP told one method works perfect for him. So i think it addressed problem. Taking only title into consideration, you may be right. :)

Comment: We should change OP's question to avoid searches leading to this.

Comment: @MaxJaderberg Histogram equalization is a form of contrast enhancement, but thresholding just creates a binary image i.e. adjusts the brightness. So this answer definitely answers OP's question, maybe not the title, but the actual question itself was answered here

Answer (score 12):

You could also check out the OpenCV CLAHE algorithm. Instead of equalizing the histogram globally, it splits up the image into tiles and equalizes those locally, then stitches them together. This can give a much better result.

With your image in OpenCV 3.0.0:

```
import cv2
inp = cv2.imread('inp.jpg',0)
clahe = cv2.createCLAHE(clipLimit=4.0, tileGridSize=(8,8))
res = clahe.apply(inp)
cv2.imwrite('res.jpg', res)
```

Gives something pretty nice

[image: After CLAHE]

Read more about it here, though it's not super helpful:
http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d5/daf/tutorial_py_histogram_equalization.html#gsc.tab=0

Answer (score 1):

Although this post is a bit aged:
What about using "cvAddWeighted( )" ?

What it does is:

```
             dst = src1*alpha + src2*beta + gamma
```

What I understand from applying brightness and contrast is, that one wants to do:

```
             dst = src*contrast + brightness;
```

so if

```
             src1  = input image
             src2  = any image of same type as src1
             alpha = contrast value
             beta  = 0.0
             gamma = brightness value
             dst   = resulting Image (must be of same type as src1)
```

One should be pretty much done with the task, no?

This approch works for me using CvMat* images

Comment: Question was asked in C

Comment: `C: void cvAddWeighted(const CvArr* src1, double alpha, const CvArr* src2, double beta, double gamma, CvArr* dst)`...not to be confused with:  `C++ addWeighted()`