# How to equalize brightness, contrast, histrograms between two images using EMGUCV

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing, emgucv

What I am doing is attempting to using EMGU to perform and AbsDiff of two images.

Given the following conditions:

1. User starts their webcam and with the webcam stationary takes a picture.
2. User moves into the frame and takes another picture (WebCam has NOT moved).

AbsDiff works well but what I'm finding is that the ISO adjustments and White Balance adjustments made by certain cameras (even on Android and iPhone) are uncontrollable to a degree.

Therefore instead of fighting a losing battle I'd like to attempt some image post processing to see if I can equalize the two.

I found the following thread but it's not helping me much: [How do I equalize contrast & brightness of images using opencv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10561222/how-do-i-equalize-contrast-brightness-of-images-using-opencv)

Can anyone offer specific details of what functions/methods/approach to take using EMGUCV?

I've tried using things like _EqualizeHist().  This yields very poor results.

Instead of equalizing the histograms for each image individually, I'd like to compare the brightness/contrast values and come up with an average that gets applied to both.

I'm not looking for someone to do the work for me (although code example would CERTAINLY be appreciated).  I'm looking for either exact guidance or some way to point the ship in the right direction.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Can you post the two images?

Comment: @Miki absolutely.  When I work tonight I will post them for reference and show what I mean.