# Fast imadjust in OpenCV and python

Tags: python, matlab, opencv, image-processing

This [has been *somewhat* answered before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39767612/what-is-the-equivalent-of-matlabs-imadjust-in-python), however the solution is extremely slow compared to [MATLAB's equivalent function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imadjust.html?requestedDomain=true). On my computer, the function takes 1.7 seconds to execute in python, while it only takes 0.009 seconds for the same image in MATLAB. The result is the same, but the speed gap is enormous.

Can this be optimized? Or are there any other python libraries that can do histogram stretching fast?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those answers are not very good. `imadjust` simply does a linear stretch. You need to find the lower and upper bound (by default it uses the 1% and 99% of the data). Once you have `lower` and `upper`, you can just

```
out = (img - lower) * (255 / (upper - lower)
np.clip(out, 0, 255, out) # in-place clipping
```

You probably need `img` to be of a floating-point type for that to work correctly.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1969274/7328782) for linear mapping in Numpy.