# The problem is that the linear image correlation does not have any effect on the images and they appear the same as the original image

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I have encountered such a problem that when displaying the original and corrected images, they do not differ from each other and there is no effect of linear image correction. Don't know what the problem might be?

```
from google.colab import drive
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow
# Uploading an image
drive.mount("/content/drive")
img = cv2.imread('./drive/MyDrive/python/bird/maxresdefault.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
# Calculating the minimum and maximum pixel values
r_min = np.min(img)
r_max = np.max(img)
# Linear image correction
img_corrected = (img - r_min) * 255.0 / (r_max - r_min)
# Converting an image to an 8-bit format
img_corrected = np.uint8(img_corrected)
img_corrected = cv2.cvtColor(img_corrected, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
# Displaying the original and corrected images
cv2_imshow(img)
cv2_imshow(img_corrected)
cv2.imwrite("./drive/MyDrive/python/bird/corrected_image.jpg", img_corrected)
img_corrected = cv2.imread("./drive/MyDrive/python/bird/corrected_image.jpg")
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The original and corrected image are shown below.And do these images differ in any way?
[image]
[image]

Comment: Maybe there is no or almost no effect of linear correction, because max and min values of the original image are already close to or equal to 255 and 0?

Answer (score 2):

As commented, the minimum and maximum are very close to 0 and 255 (the actual values are 0 and 254).

Assume `r_min` = `0` and `r_max` = `255`.
Assign the values in the linear correlation formula:

`(img - r_min) * 255.0 / (r_max - r_min)` = `(img - 0) * 255.0 / (255 - 0)`
= `(img - 0) * 1` = `img`

As you can see, the output is equal to the input (no change).

---

We may use `lin_stretch_img` method from my [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75625939/4926757):

```
def lin_stretch_img(img, low_prc, high_prc):
    """ 
    Apply linear "stretch" - low_prc percentile goes to 0, 
    and high_prc percentile goes to 255.
    The result is clipped to [0, 255] and converted to np.uint8
    """
    lo, hi = np.percentile(img, (low_prc, high_prc))  # Example: 1% - Low percentile, 99% - High percentile

    if lo == hi:
        return np.full(img.shape, 128, np.uint8)  # Protection: return gray image if lo = hi.

    stretch_img = (img.astype(np.float32) - lo) * (255/(hi-lo))  # Linear stretch: lo goes to 0, hi to 255.
    stretch_img = stretch_img.clip(0, 255).astype(np.uint8)  # Clip range to [0, 255] and convert to uint8
```

Instead of linear stretching the image between the minimum and maximum, we may stretch between some lower [percentile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentile) and upper percentile.

All the pixels below the lower percentile are going to be zeros (1% of the output pixels are going to be black).
All the pixels above the upper percentile are going to be 255 (1% of the output pixels are going to be white).
The pixels between the lower and upper percentile are "stretched" lineary.
We are going to get higher contrast in expanse of saturated and "sub-saturated" pixels.

Example with percentiles 10 and 90 (a bit of exaggeration for demonstration):

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def lin_stretch_img(img, low_prc, high_prc):
    lo, hi = np.percentile(img, (low_prc, high_prc))  # Example: 1% - Low percentile, 99% - High percentile

    if lo == hi:
        return np.full(img.shape, 128, np.uint8)  # Protection: return gray image if lo = hi.

    stretch_img = (img.astype(np.float32) - lo) * (255/(hi-lo))  # Linear stretch: lo goes to 0, hi to 255.
    stretch_img = stretch_img.clip(0, 255).astype(np.uint8)  # Clip range to [0, 255] and convert to uint8
    return stretch_img

img = cv2.imread('maxresdefault.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
#r_min = np.min(img)  # 0
#r_max = np.max(img)  # 254
# Linear image correction
low_prc = 10
high_prc = 90
img_corrected = lin_stretch_img(img, low_prc, high_prc)

# Displaying the original and corrected images (without Google colab).
cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.imshow('img_corrected', img_corrected)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

---

In the above example, `lo` = `32` and `hi` = `183`.

`(img - lo) * 255.0 / (hi - lo)` = `(img - 32) * 255.0 / (183 - 32)`
= `(img - 32) * 1.69`

Scaling by 1.69 is the cause for the higher contrast.

---

Output:
[image]

In the image above, 10% of the pixels are black (value `0`) and 10% are white (value `255`).

---

Note about computation time:

The `percentile` computation requires sorting - complexity of sorting is O(n*log(n)).
In case we care about real-time considerations - say we want to implement `lin_stretch_img` in C, we may solve it without sorting.

There is an O(n) solution for finding the percentiles.
The solution applies the case where all values are integers (i.e pixels type is `uint8`).

The solution applies histogram collection, cumulative sum of histogram, and iterating the cumulative sum.
There is an example in the [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44611551/4926757).

It may not be faster in Python, but the C implementation is going to be much faster.